# Any angular app is not running on any browser

Tags: angular

[localhost took too long to respond...ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHm02.png)

[image]

- Any Angular app is not running on any browser.
- Tried to uninstall it and clean the cache again install it but it doesn't work either.
- Update package.json too console shows that compiled successfully.

Comment: Hi Helly, welcome to stackoverflow. You have tagged the question for both angular and angularjs. Just in case if you are not aware, both are completely different and may attract attention from audience with a completely different skill set.

Comment: Can you please update the answer to include some steps on how you reached this error and how you are trying to run the app.

Comment: With these information, one can only guess what you did. This looks like you're somehow terminating your development server - but as already mentioned, please provide your exact steps that lead to thos problem (what commands are your running, what is the output on terminal, etc)

Comment: If your'e using angular-cli, Are you write **ng serve** in a console in the application folder before ask for localhost:4200 in navigator ?

Comment: What is your terminal input and output? What do you write on your console and what exactly does it say? To start the development server, please mind that the correct command is, as mentioned, ng serve and not ng build!

Comment: i am right now working in angular cli and using "ng serve -o" to run the application

Comment: It's not working in any application even though it's new  application, its not working  either.Facing the same problem again and againg whether its new or existing.

Comment: console output is :: **Date: 2018-11-11T10:50:21.600Z**
**Hash: 07ab1847afafcf0fed6f**
**Time: 10582ms**
**chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 12.7 kB [initial] [rendered]**
**chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 223 kB [initial] [rendered]**
**chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]**
**chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.2 kB [initial] [rendered]**
**chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.55 MB [initial] [rendered]**
**i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the provided information, it is difficult to analyze the problem. 
Still, I will try to give you a few hints on what may be the problem in your case.

- Check if you are running the correct command. If you are using the angular cli, the correct command to start a development server is `ng serve`
- Check if you are opening the correct port. The default port is `4200`, but depending on your configuration this might not be the case. To be 100% sure run `ng serve --port=4200`
- Make sure that nothing is blocking the selected port. Usually, the cli will throw an error message if the port is blocked. Again, to make sure, either run the appropriate command for your OS to check if the selected port is blocked or just try a different port (e.g. `ng serve --port=5678`) and open your browser at that adress.
- If you are behind a corporate proxy or VPN of some kind, add localhost to your NO_PROXY environment variable. This should usually not be a problem, but you never know with corporate proxies.

Again, it would be really helpful if you further provided the console outputs.

Comment: Date: 2018-11-11T10:50:21.600Z
Hash: 07ab1847afafcf0fed6f
Time: 10582ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 12.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 223 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.55 MB [initial] [rendered]
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.

Comment: again facing the same problems ..tried everything which is mentioned in your hint..and thank you for helping..!!

Comment: Did the output say something like 'development server started on port...'?

Comment: @pascalpuetz hi i get some issue, and CLI told me what 'Development Server is listening on localhost:4200' but when i open browser facing white page. Another angular project works fine

Comment: @d2207 can you see any error in console (also browser console)? A white page usually means the app could not start because of some compile error/runtime error.

Comment: @pascalpuetz yes it was some error in browser console, `MatDialogModule` didnt provide in `app.module.ts` i resolve it, thx u)